# Speed up loop operation

Tags: r, performance, loops, bootstrapping

I need to run a coverage probability test on different sample sizes and censoring proportions. I need to replicate 1000 bootstrap samples using the `boot` function in R. I have run the code for up to 3-8 hours and I have no idea regarding the runtime.

```
set.seed(20)
lambda <- 0.02
beta <- 0.5
alpha <- 0.05
n <- 140
N <- 1000
lambda_hat <- NULL
beta_hat <- NULL
cp <- NULL
bp_lambda <- matrix(NA, nrow=N, ncol=2)
bp_beta <- matrix(NA, nrow=N, ncol=2)

for (i in 1:N) {
  u <- runif(n)
  c_i <- rexp(n, 0.0001)
  t_i <- (log(1 - (1/lambda)*log(1 - u)))^(1/beta)
  s_i <- 1*(t_i < c_i)
  t <- pmin(t_i, c_i)
  data <- data.frame(u, t_i, c_i, s_i, t)
  
  estimates.boot <- function(data, j){
    data <- data[j, ]
    data0 <- data[which(data$s_i == 0), ] #uncensored data
    data1 <- data[which(data$s_i == 1), ] #right censored data
    data
    
    library(maxLik)
    LLF <- function(para) {
      t1 <- data$t_i
      
      lambda <- para[1]
      beta <- para[2]
      e <- s_i*log(lambda*t1^(beta - 1)*beta*exp(t1^beta)*exp(lambda*(1 - exp(t1^beta))))
      r <- (1 - s_i)*log(exp(lambda*(1 - exp(t1^beta))))
      f <-  sum(e + r)
      return(f)
    }
    mle <-  maxLik(LLF, start=c(para=c(0.02, 0.5)))
    lambda_hat[i] <- mle$estimate[1]
    beta_hat[i] <- mle$estimate[2]
    return(c(lambda_hat[i], beta_hat[i]))
  }
  library(boot)
  bootstrap <- boot(data, estimates.boot, 1000)
  bootlambda <- bootstrap$t[, 1]
  klambda <- bootlambda[order(bootlambda)]
  bp_lambda[i, ] <- c(klambda[25], klambda[975])
  bootbeta <- bootstrap$t[, 2]
  kbeta <- bootbeta[order(bootbeta)]
  bp_beta[i, ] <- c(kbeta[25], kbeta[975])
}
left_lambda <- sum(bp_lambda[, 1]>lambda)/N
right_lambda <- sum(bp_lambda[, 2]<lambda)/N
total_lambda <- left_lambda + right_lambda
left_beta <- sum(bp_beta[, 1] > beta)/N
right_beta <- sum(bp_beta[, 2]<beta)/N
total_beta <- left_beta + right_beta
sealphahat <-  sqrt(alpha*(1 - alpha)/N)
antilambda <- total_lambda>(alpha + 2.58*sealphahat)
conlambda <- total_lambda<(alpha - 2.58*sealphahat)
asymlambda <- (max(left_lambda, right_lambda)/min(left_lambda, right_lambda)) > 1.5
antibeta <- total_beta > (alpha + 2.58*sealphahat)
conbeta <- total_beta < (alpha - 2.58*sealphahat)
asymbeta <- (max(left_beta, right_beta)/min(left_beta, right_beta)) > 1.5
anti <- antilambda + antibeta
con <- conlambda + conbeta
asym <- asymlambda + asymbeta
cbind(anti, con, asym)
```

Anyone have idea how to speed up the operation?

Comment: First step is to remove your function definitions from the loop and place them at the top of the code.  This will improve readability and offer some performance benefits by avoiding redefining the same function over and over

Comment: If you run this with N=2 you get rather worrisome warnings that suggest the algorithm is flawed: `warnings()[1:3]
Warning messages:
1: In log(lambda * t1^(beta - 1) * beta * exp(t1^beta) *  ... : NaNs produced
2: In log(lambda * t1^(beta - 1) * beta * exp(t1^beta) *  ... : NaNs produced
3: In log(lambda * t1^(beta - 1) * beta * exp(t1^beta) *  ... : NaNs produced`

Comment: So speeding up a procedure that hasn't been debugged yet seems putting effort in the wrong place.

Comment: And if you verify your algorithm works and you want it to go faster, your best bet will probably be to run it in parallel. My guess is 95% or more of the time is spent by `maxLik` and `boot` calls, meaning edits to the code that don't impact those 2 calls will make a negligible difference in the run time. You could verify my assumption by profiling the code. Pre-allocating `lambda_hat` and `beta_hat`*might* help a little bit.

Comment: Did you notice, that you split into `data0` and `data1` but don't use it later?

Comment: @Dave2e I don’t think that’s a serious performance issue. I’d expect the JIT compiler to take care of this (but haven’t actually checked).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to apply a random sampling to an estimation function (inner bootstrap) and randomly sample the entire process again (outer bootstrap).

Consequently we could write an estimation function `estimate()` using `replicate()` (to avoid `boot:boot`) and a function for the inner bootstrap `innerBoot()`. In the latter we could use `matrixStats::rowQuantiles` for fast computation of the quantiles you want.

I essentially used your code, just fixed a few issues that prevented the code from running.

```
estimate <- function() {
  u <- runif(n)
  c_i <- rexp(n, 0.0001)
  t_i <- (log(1 - (1/lambda)*log(1 - u)))^(1/beta)
  s_i <- 1*(t_i < c_i)
  t <- pmin(t_i, c_i)
  LLF <- function(para) {
    lambda <- para[1]
    beta <- para[2]
    e <- s_i*log(lambda*t_i^(beta - 1)*beta*exp(t_i^beta)*exp(lambda*(1 - exp(t_i^beta))))
    r <- (1 - s_i)*log(exp(lambda*(1 - exp(t_i^beta))))
    return(sum(e + r))
  }
  mle <- maxLik::maxLik(LLF, start=c(para=c(0.02, 0.5)))
  return(setNames(mle$estimate, c('lambda_hat', 'beta_hat')))
}

innerBoot <- function() {
  boot <- replicate(N, estimate())
  return(matrixStats::rowQuantiles(boot, p=c(.025, .975)))
}
```

We also perform the outer bootstrap with `replicate()`. I wrap it here in `system.time()` to get a time measurement.

```
lambda <- 0.02
beta <- 0.5
alpha <- 0.05
n <- 140
# N <- 1000
N <- 10  ## for testing
seed <- 42
set.seed(seed)

tm <- system.time(
  BA <- replicate(N, innerBoot())
)
```

I got these measurements,

```
tm
#   user  system elapsed   ## N = 10
# 1.055   0.000   1.057 
#    user  system elapsed   ## N = 100
# 102.012   0.227 102.489
```

which indicates that for `N <- 1000` about 167 minutes are to be expected.

The result is an array of dim 2x2xN.

```
> dim(BA)
[1]  2  2 100
```

To calculate the summaries we may easily refer to the respective cells.

```
boot_sum <- function(BA) {
  left_lambda <- sum(BA[1, 1, ] > lambda)/N
  right_lambda <- sum(BA[1, 2, ] >< lambda)/N
  left_beta <- sum(BA[2, 1, ] > beta)/N
  right_beta <- sum(BA[2, 2, ] < beta)/N
  total_lambda <- left_lambda + right_lambda
  total_beta <- left_beta + right_beta
  sealphahat <-  sqrt(alpha*(1 - alpha)/N)
  antilambda <- total_lambda > (alpha + 2.58*sealphahat)
  conlambda <- total_lambda < (alpha - 2.58*sealphahat)
  asymlambda <- (max(left_lambda, right_lambda)/min(left_lambda, right_lambda)) > 1.5
  antibeta <- total_beta > (alpha + 2.58*sealphahat)
  conbeta <- total_beta < (alpha - 2.58*sealphahat)
  asymbeta <- (max(left_beta, right_beta)/min(left_beta, right_beta)) > 1.5
  anti <- antilambda + antibeta
  con <- conlambda + conbeta
  asym <- asymlambda + asymbeta
  return(cbind(anti, con, asym))
}

boot_sum(BA)
#      anti con asym
# [1,]    2   0    2
```

**Note:** You should definitely check the code in the body of `estimate()` (i.e. run it manually several times without bootstrapping), as it throws warnings every now and then, probably there is a mistake in how you define `LLF()`.

```
Warning messages:
1: In log(lambda * t_i^(beta - 1) * beta * exp(t_i^beta) * exp(lambda *  :
  NaNs produced
2: In log(lambda * t_i^(beta - 1) * beta * exp(t_i^beta) * exp(lambda *  :
  NaNs produced
```

Also I'm not sure if the summary calculation currently makes much sense.

My advice is to check your likelihood function and the summary by 1. manually run the lines, 2. starting with a very small N like 10 or so, to see if calculations make sense.

Once you've checked that, it's worth to wait the ~167 minutes to wait for the result.

Or parallelize `innerBoot()`, which is about 80% faster overall (using 7 cores), as follows:

```
innerBootParallel <- function() {
  boot <- parSapply(cl, 1:N, function(i) estimate())
  return(matrixStats::rowQuantiles(boot, p=c(.025, .975)))
}
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterExport(cl, c('estimate', 'n', 'lambda', 'N', 'beta'))
clusterSetRNGStream(cl, seed)
BA <- replicate(N, innerBootParallel())
stopCluster(cl)
boot_sum(BA)
```